# Error al bajar un JSON con la librería AFNetworking

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, objective-c

Tengo una aplicación que hay que retocar y debo añadir un sistema con `webservice`.

Tengo que bajar un JSON de un `webservice` (de un enlace), para ello uso la librería AFNetworking. El problema es que el código hace un "failure" cuando hago el POST. El enlace está bien puesto, y también he agregado al `info.plist` el registro "App Transport Security Settings" con "Allow arbitrary loads" a YES.

El mismo código me funciona en otra aplicación, por lo que creo que debe ser alguna configuración de la aplicación que estoy retocando.

Este es el código:

```
self.manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[self.manager.responseSerializer setAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json",  nil]];
[self.manager POST:@"http://webejemplo.org/init.json" parameters:nil 
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSDictionary* responseObject) {
   if ([[responseObject valueForKey:@"pass"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
      completion(nil,[responseObject valueForKey:@"version"]);
   }
}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
   completion(error,nil);
}];
```

Cuando debugo me salta a "failure" como si no encontrara el enlace

Comment: Buenas @Popularfan, sería de gran ayuda para analizar mejor y más rápido el código que editases el post con la parte del código que estás retocando.

Comment: Ok, acabo de agregar la parte de código que no me funciona